# showhide function in dynamically created form does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a webpage with a form that is created dynamically by means of javascript (jquery). For each (repetitive) set of form elements a Show/hide function is added to show and hide the elements, and I dont get this show/hide code working - I suspect the error is located as indicated within the code below, and I think I struggle to put the quotes at the right place (?) The console indicates an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " which I dont understand; when excluding the suspected erroneous line there are no further errors and I dont see where this '}' shows up where it's not supposed to show up.

Javascript code:

```
function ShowHide(id) {
    $(id).toggle();
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    var buildform = function () {
        var form ='<div id="form">'

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            form += '<div id="filename"' + i + '> Document  </div> </td>';
            //error in next line (?)
            form += '<button onclick="ShowHide(\'#filename'+ i +'\')">  Show/hide document </button> </td> </tr>';

        } //for i
        form += '</div>'; //id="form"
        console.log('FORM: '+form);
        return
    } //buildform()

   $("#wrapper").append(form);

}); //$(document).
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Output by javaconsole():

```
<div id="form"><div id="filename"0> Document  </div><button onclick="ShowHide('#filename0')">  Show/hide document </button></div><div id="filename"1> Document  </div><button onclick="ShowHide('#filename1')">  Show/hide document </button></div>
```

Comment: I notice the issues you're still having in the comments, and have updated my answer.  Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: I just update the code above and identified the problem in the output; as one can see the 'filename' div id was not formatted properly. After fixing that it worked. thnx for all your help.

Comment: Any time!  You should accept either answer for future readers, so they know what worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quotes are wrong.

```
  form += '<td> <button onclick="ShowHide(\'#filename'+ i +  '\')">  Show/hide document </button> </td> </tr>';
```

I matched the quotes in parenthesis, and escaped them with `\`.  Also, you're saving your created html, but never show anywhere that it would actually output the html to the page.  You need to actually output the information created.  For example:

The HTML:

```
<div ="outputContainer"></div>
```

Inside your function:

```
$("#outputContainer").html(form);
```

Comment: thnx. I append the created form to a div element

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes correct

Please change the line:

```
form += '<td> <button onclick="ShowHide("#filename'+ i +')">  Show/hide document </button> </td> </tr>';
```

to this:

```
form += '<td> <button onclick="ShowHide(\'#filename'+ i +'\')">  Show/hide document </button> </td> </tr>';
                                        ^                 ^
```

Comment: thnx both; with your solution the error shown by the console is gone. However, the ShowHide function still does not seem to work; I tested that the function is called when pressing the button(s)

Comment: You're saving the function to a variable, and saving the form info to a variable as well.  Where are you setting outputting it to the page?